# Diameters of permutation groups with transitive generators

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, asymptotics, permutations, permutation-groups

Suppose that for a permutation puzzle on $n$ elements we have a subroutine to place any $m>3$ elements in arbitrary positions (possibly scrambling the rest).  Can we solve the puzzle (if it is solvable) in $O(n/m)$ subroutine applications (allowing $O(n/m)$ other moves)?

In other words, suppose that we have a set of permutations $S$ such that by picking an element of $S$ we can move any $m>3$ elements arbitrarily.  Is every permutation generated by $S$ a product of $O(n/m)$ permutations in $S$?

$S$ is 4-transitive, so excepting the four Mathieu groups, every even permutation is generated by $S$.  For $m$ equaling 2 or 3, other permutation groups are possible, and I do not know if they muddy the picture.  $m=1$ does not work since $S = \{ (123...n)^i: i < n \} ∪ \{(12)\}$ generates $S_n$ while requiring a quadratic number of moves.  Also, a perhaps easier special case is $m=\lceil εn \rceil$ and hence $O(1)$ moves from $S$.

I suspect that every transitive permutation group on $n$ elements has diameter $O(n^2)$, but I could only find a quasipolynomial upper bound, [On the diameter of permutation groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.3550) by Helfgott and Seress.  Thus, I should probably expect only a partial answer to the question.

In contrast to the above, a single permutation on $n$ elements can have order $e^{(1 + o(1)) \sqrt{n \ln n}}$ by consisting of many disjoint cycles of relatively prime length.  However, as soon as we allow mixing, I expect that in some vague sense we get maximal (or random-like) mixing — if only we could formalize and prove it.  See also my earlier question [Permutation groups with diameter O(n log n)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320016/permutation-groups-with-diameter-on-log-n).

Comment: Just to make explicit something you have probably already noticed: you are not going to get a better-than-quasipolynomial bound for $m$ bounded unless you prove a better-than-quasipolynomial bound for every generating set of $S_n$. The reason is that, if $S$ generates $S_n$, then $S^{n (n-1) \dotsc (n-m+1)} \subset S^{n^m}$ is an $m$-transitive set (i.e., moves $m$ elements arbitrarily).

Comment: Also - a very weak version (polynomial diameter for $m\geq n/2$) can be proved easily using 19th-century techniques; see Lemma 3.12 in my paper with Seress (which is just an adaptation of an old proof by Bochert (1889)). You can go down a bit if you are willing to undergo more pain (https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.1596). AFAIK, the question with $k\sim \epsilon n$ is still open, though.